# How to avoid taxonomy terms other than current language terms in taxonomy menu?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, routes, i18n-l10n

Vocabulary settings:

- Per language terms. Different terms will be allowed for each language
  and they can be translated.

I translate one term to other language (different than default), but this term is in the taxonomy menu on default language too, could somebody give me any advice?

**[EDIT]**

I'am trying with a [hook](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_translated_menu_link_alter/6):

```
function myalter_translated_menu_link_alter(&$item, $map) {
    if ($item['module'] == 'taxonomy_menu') {
    $t = _taxonomy_menu_get_item($item['mlid']);        
    if ($t['tid'] > 0) { 
        $term = taxonomy_get_term($t['tid']);
            global $language;
            if ($term->language != $language->language) {
                unset($item);
            }
      }
    }
}
```

It seems that this hook catch taxonomy menu terms with language other than current, but there are still displayed in the menu.